# Regular expression - how to write it?

Tags: regex

Giving the following examples:

```
217_beige_65D
372_black_70F
401_beige_100GG
```

I need a regular expression that will extract the colour and size (size is always at the end (3-5 characters for example 65D, 100E) ).

Help pls.

Comment: Just split it by `_` in your language of choice (which is unkown yet...). Please read the tag description that clearly states to name the programming language of choice as there are differences in the regex engines.

Comment: @Jan Altough I think, you gave the best solution, the question was simply about a regex. And yes, there are differences. But this is a simple example. So there is no need to provide a programming language. Maybe there is none...

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can extract them in JavaScript unsing Regex:

```js
const text = '217_beige_65D';
const regex = /.+_(.+)_(.+)/;
const result = text.match(regex); // ["217_beige_65D", "beige", "65D", ...]
const color = result[1];
const size = result[2];
```

or use the split method like that:

```js
const text = '217_beige_65D';
const result = text.split('_'); // ["217", "beige", "65D"]
const color = result[1];
const size = result[2];
```

Comment: If it is important, that there are 3-5 characters: `/^.+_([a-z]+)_([0-9A-Z]{3-5})$/`. Use `$`, so it must be at the end, and be careful with "." because it can be an underscore. But I think the above solution works fine if the given example don't changes.